# Using jQuery.load() function to load an image

Tags: jquery

When I execute the code below, I get an unreadable image as below

```
function example() {
  $('#placeholder').load("ylogo_purple_t1.gif");
}
```

So, how to use jQuery.load() to load an image?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load will give you *contents*, use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead like this:

```
function example() {
  $('#placeholder').append('<img src="ylogo_purple_t1.gif" />');
}
```

Comment: So, besides using others function, jQuery.load() is not suitable for loading an image?

Comment: @CharlesYeung: `load` is usually used to load html contents from another page. If your image is part of html in some other html page, you can use it. If you want to load an image just by its path or name, you should use `attr('src')` or `append/prepend/before/after/etc` depending on whether you have `img` tag present in your current html where you want to put image.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the image's blob into an element, and the browser is trying to parse it as text.

```
$('#placeholder img').attr("src", "ylogo_purple_t1.gif");
```